# Proguard retain R classes

Tags: android, proguard

I am integrating Amazon's ads into my app and I use Proguard.  They are telling me if I'm using Proguard that I have to "ensure the R class retains its name during the obfuscation process"

Does anyone know what the means and, if so, how I can accomplish that?

**UPDATE**

I've tried a bunch of different option and I still get an error from Amazon's SDK that my resources are obfuscated.  I've tried:

```
-keepnames com.my.app.*.R;

-keeppackagenames com.my.app.*.R;

-keepclassmembers com.my.app.*.R;

-keep class com.my.app.*.R;

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: What are those * doing in the package names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proguard obfuscates your code, by replacing all class names and methods with A, B, C, D and so on.

To retain the class names, add `-keepnames` to your proguard file.

Example could be `-keepnames com.example.myproject.R`

Also see this SO post: [Proguard keep class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971810/proguard-keep-class-names)

Also see the proguard project for more information about what it does and what options there are to use: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried everything and I cannot get Proguard to no obfuscate my resources. I updated the OP to how what I've tried, so far.