# How to configure ProGuard keep options for multiple namespaces?

Tags: android, proguard

I understand that the [keep options of ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage) can be used with wildcards to include full namespaces. E.g.:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.yourpackage.** {
    # relevant configuration
}
```

Can the same configuration be applied to *multiple* namespaces without having to repeat the configuration twice?

For example, is something like the following possible to include both the `io.` and `com.` namespace?

```
-keepclassmembers class [com|io].yourcompany.yourpackage.** {
    # relevant configuration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by [ProGuard's Class Specifications](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage).

Limited options, mimicking regular expressions, are available. But, these do not include the pipe (`|`) typically used for denoting options.

However, *"[f]or additional flexibility, class names can actually be comma-separated lists of class names, with optional `!` negators, just like file name filters. This notation doesn't look very Java-like, so it should be used with moderation."*

Who cares about not looking very "Java-like", I just don't want to repeat myself. Besides, I'm using Kotlin. =) The following should thus work:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.yourpackage.**, io.yourcompany.yourpackage.** {
    # relevant configuration
}
```