# Keep methods and fields with ProGuard

Tags: java, proguard

Using -keep does not keep methods and fields. They are obfuscated but I do not want to obfuscate some classes with methods and fields.

Rules used

```
-target '11'
-keep public class com.example.MyClass
```

If I use  and  proguards returns a class which Java Decompiler can not decompile (message 'Internal Error' after decompiling) e.g.

```
-keep public class com.example.MyClass {
   <methods>;
   <fields>;
}
```

I tried also [*;}.

Is there something wrong/bug with ProGuard Version 7.3.0 and using option target '11'?

Comment: Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971810/proguard-keep-class-names), are you looking for `-keepnames class com.example.MyClass`? ("keepnames" instead of "keep" and no "public")

Comment: no, that does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep interface com.example.ApiContext { *; }
-keep abstract class com.example.ControlContext { *; }
-keep class com.example.CloseInstanceContext { *; }
```

I think 'abstract' was the problem, that it did not work.